# margin-right of <div> in <div> not being shown in flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to create a container `div` wrapping another `div` that scrolls and has an equal margin around all sides. The issue is the `margin` setting is not being reflected on the right side and the `.inner` `div` only scrolls to the end of the `width` setting.

I have read other posts and found it may be related to the way the `width` is being set but am unable to get the css quite right for my case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  
  .outer {
    height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  .inner {
    min-width: 2500px;
    min-height: 2500px;
    margin: 12.5px;
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried to use `padding` in `.outer` and also various `width` settings including `calc(x% - ypx)`

I would like to be able to set the `width` of the container `.outer` so that it is not 100% of the page.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Perhaps you could add another `div` around `.inner` and set a padding to it

Comment: Try `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:inherit` in inner div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `.inner` to `display:inline-block` achieves the desired behaviour.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .outer {
      height: 600px;
      overflow: scroll;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .inner {
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 2500px;
      min-height: 2500px;
      margin: 12.5px;
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class='outer'>
      <div class='inner'></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner element has a `min-width` greater than the available horizontal space provided by the container. I've removed this attribute. Please review the snippet below.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.outer {
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 85%;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 2500px;
  margin: 12.5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by the OP, if a fixed width is used for the inner element, than as you scroll to the right, no right margin is displayed. I did a bit of a trick and faked a `right-margin` by setting a `right-border` on the inner element, as follows:

```css
.outer {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 85%;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 360px;
  margin: 12px;
  background-color: green;
  border-right: 12px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to specify a fixed width for the inner div and then have the extra margin round all sides. Is there a means to do this? I've also unsuccessfully tried to add more divs but this isn't really the way I'd like to go about it. With the min-width removed there is no horizontal scroll anymore.

Comment: Please review the updated solution. As you point out the margin is not displayed if `inner` has a fixed width, so I made a fake margin using border. Hope this helps. I also removed the flex attributes - they are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this. Please see my own answer for a working solution without the need of a "fake margin". I added the flex attributes as partial completeness in order to help find a solution relevant to my constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I have just added `overflow:inherit` in inner div css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  
  .outer {
    height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  .inner {
    min-width: 2500px;
    min-height: 2500px;
    margin: 12.5px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow:inherit;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be showing the margin on the right?